# Reflect enum inspection is not yet implemented

Tags: debugging, rust, timer, game-engine, bevy

How can I reflect the mode of Timer so that it's visible in the Bevy debug interface - "inspector egui"? Other stats are visible like the current time, a pausing option, etc., just the mode.

[image: Image showing the inspector egui]

This is my code:

```
#[derive(Reflect, Component, Default)]
#[reflect(Component)]
pub struct Tower {
  shooting_timer: Timer
}
```

In [this repo](https://github.com/jakobhellermann/bevy-inspector-egui) in [this file](https://github.com/jakobhellermann/bevy-inspector-egui/blob/98292c94754f244f03898d7f0a5f5b2b5596903d/src/reflect/mod.rs) on [line 127](https://github.com/jakobhellermann/bevy-inspector-egui/blob/98292c94754f244f03898d7f0a5f5b2b5596903d/src/reflect/mod.rs#L127) this error is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should "just work" now. I tested with bevy_inspector_egui version `0.17.0`.

[image: World inspector window showing timer's fields properly displayed]

Here's the code I used to test it and produce that image:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy_inspector_egui::quick::WorldInspectorPlugin;

#[derive(Reflect, Component, Default)]
#[reflect(Component)]
struct Tower {
    shooting_timer: Timer,
}

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugin(WorldInspectorPlugin)
        .register_type::<Tower>()
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .run()
}

fn setup(mut commands: Commands) {
    commands.spawn(Tower::default());
}
```